# Always build package from source in Homebrew

Tags: catalina, homebrew

I installed macOS Catalina by using [macOS Catalina Patcher](http://dosdude1.com/catalina/) on my Mac mini 2010 and it works like a charm. But I am facing the problem described on this [thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macos-10-14-mojave-on-unsupported-macs-thread.2121473/post-27026470). The package bottles (prebuilt binary) has built and optimized with some modern CPU [instructions support](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1402#issuecomment-499883333) by default on macOS Catalina, So it doesn't run on my old machine that has [Intel Core2](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Intel_Core_2) Duo. I always get `Illegal Instruction: 4` errors when I run the command.

So my question is, Instead of pouring bottles, I always run the command `brew install -s <package name>` to get rid of the problem by building source from scratch. It's annoying to add `-s` flag manually every time. Is it possible to ask Homebrew to always build package from source?

Comment: If there was a way, it would likely entail setting an environment variable - but I don't see anything that tells brew to always install from source. https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#environment